# Laravel Passing Arguments to Function without following the sequence

Tags: php, laravel, arguments, parameter-passing, laravel-8

I used to code in [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) and I want to check if this method exist in Laravel as well. When passing arguments to a Rails function, I can pass them with their name just like JSON. I am not sure if I can do this as well in Laravel.

Ruby on Rails sample Code:

```rb
//function 1 with arguments
def cal_salary(basic:, commission: 0, deduction: 0)
    return basic + commission - deduction
end

//function 2(call function 1)
def sales_salary
    return cal_salary(basic: 1200, commission: 1200)
    //will get 2400in result
end

//function 3
def support_salary
    return cal_salary(basic: 2000, deduction: 200)
    //will get 1800
end
```

I can also just call

```rb
cal_salary(basic: 2000) // return 2000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. But that has nothing to do with Laravel because Laravel is just a framework. This is a language feature added to PHP in version 8 and called [named function arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.named-arguments).